Trigram index is slow for common terms
I have a PostgreSQL database with bunch of string columns in a table with a trigram index on them using pg_trgm. They are queried like this
SELECT [...] FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn ILIKE '%searchterm%';

For queries with very specific search terms this works very nicely. There are a few hundred thousand rows in that table, and some of these columns can contain a large amount of text (most of them are reasonably short strings though).
The problem is that this doesn't work nicely when the search terms are common and appear in many of the rows. For search queries with specific search terms this query completes in milliseconds, for terms that match ~80% of all rows it takes tens of seconds. The trigram indexes are actually used in almost all queries, even the slow ones.
I know that this is probably inherent to how this index works and not easily fixable, but I'm mostly looking for ways to handle these cases better than just waiting for a query timeout. Searching for these terms isn't very useful anyway, it won't filter out enough rows. But I can't prevent users from entering these terms, so I'd like to fail a bit more graceful than with a query timeout, if possible.
First, are there any ways to increase the performance of this kind of query? Are there better types of indexes for this or other ways to tune the performance of the index? I'm intentionally using trigram indexes here and not the Postgres fulltext search as stemming would be counter-productive here. The search terms are often not English words and in my first experiments stemming was harmful for certain queries as it e.g. trimmed away parts of domain-specific abbreviations or terms.
Is there a way to detect cases like this where the search term is excessively unspecific? If it isn't possible to make these queries fast enough the next best thing would be to not run them and timeout but to show the user much earlier, useful feedback that their search terms are problematic.

Please show an example plan for a too-slow query.  In particular, is the row estimate about right, or is it way off? Also, what is the version?

You could preface the real query run by doing an 'EXPLAIN' of the query, and then throw an error back to the user if the resulting row estimate were too high for the query to be meaningful.
You could automatically add a LIMIT to the query. This would promote switching to a seq scan rather than a bitmap scan when the search is believed to be unselective, and then the LIMIT would kick in and reduce the run time of the seq scan (but even if it kept using the bitmap scan, that should also be much faster as long as most of the time goes to the bitmap heap scan, not the bitmap index scan.)
You could try setting gin_fuzzy_search_limit, but in my experience this is unreliable and seems to be buggy.
You could try to figure out why it is so slow.  Returning 80% of a few hundred thousand rows is not going to by very fast, but it probably shouldn't take 10s of seconds either.
You could just lower the timeout to the point where it times out within a reasonable time period when given bad input.
You could have some patience and rely on user (self) education. They will probably learn that some types of searches are just not worth running, because they take too long or return too many rows to be useful. Especially if you help them learn this.
